# Why is R requesting an additional TRUE/FALSE

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am trying to count the number of ATG codons in a randomly generated chain of DNA and create a histogram:

```
s1 = makeDNA(500)    
count = 0
n = 100
totCount = vector("numeric", n)
for(j in 1:n){
  s1 = makeDNA(500) 
  count = 0
  for(i in 1:500){
    if(s1[i] == "A" & s1[i+1] == "T" & s1[i+2] == "G"){
      count = count + 1
    }
  }
  totCount[j] = count
}
```

When I run this code R gives the following error:

```
Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
Error in if (s1[i] == "A" & s1[i + 1] == "T" & s1[i + 2] == "G") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: Nothing `==`'s NA. And there were no si's at 501 or 502.

Comment: Where does the `makeDNA` function come from? You either need to tell us what package to load, provide the code for that function, or just give us `s1` by `dput(s1)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this code:

```
for(i in 1:500){
    if(s1[i] == "A" & s1[i+1] == "T" & s1[i+2] == "G"){
      count = count + 1
    }
```

When `i == 499`, then `i + 2 == 501`. The object `s1` is only 500 elements long. There is no 501st element, so R returns `NA`. Nothing is equal to `NA`, even `NA`, and so your logical operators return `NA`, when a `TRUE` or `FALSE` is expected. Modify to the following and you should be good.

```
for(i in 1:498){
        if(s1[i] == "A" & s1[i+1] == "T" & s1[i+2] == "G"){
          count = count + 1
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

[Ben Norris' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64093133/3817004) explains nicely what has caused the error in the `for` loop and how to avoid it.

However, the `for` loop can be replaced by vectorized code which is much more efficient in many use case. Performance or execution speed likely may become an issue with the volume of genomic data.

Here are two vectorized alternatives which are much faster than the innermost `for` loop (and require less coding). I have benchmarked some more approaches but these two were the fastest.

### OP's `for` loop

```
m <- 500L
s1 <- makeDNA(m) 
count <- 0L
for(i in seq_len(m-2L)) {
  if(s1[i] == "A" & s1[i+1] == "T" & s1[i+2] == "G") {
    count <- count + 1L
  }
}
```

The code has been parameterized to study varying problem sizes. The OP has not posted the code for `makeDNA()` so I made up my own:

```
makeDNA <- function(n) sample(c("A", "T", "G"), n, TRUE)
```

### 1st alternative: *subset, shift, and sum*

Here, three subsets of length `m - 2L` each starting at position 1, 2, and 3, resp., are  picked from of `s1` and are combined in the boolean expression. `sum()` counts all occurrences of `TRUE` in the resulting logical vector:

```
s1 <- makeDNA(m) 
sum(s1[1:(m-2L)] == "A" & s1[2:(m-1L)] == "T" & s1[3:m] == "G")
```

### 2nd alternative: string operations

```
library(magrittr)
s1 <- makeDNA(m) 
stringi::stri_join(s1, collapse = "") %>% stringi::stri_count_fixed("ATG")
```

Here, the vector of characters is collapsed into a single string. Then, the number of occurrences of "ATG" in the string is counted. The `stringi` package is used for the string operations. Also, piping is used to improve readability.

### Benchmark

For benchmarking, the length `m` of the character vector is varied as well as the number of repetitions `n`. For the vectorized variants, the outer `for` loop is replaced by the `replicate()` function. `bench()` automatically checks that the result of all 3 expressions is equal.

```
library(magrittr)
library(bench)
bm <- press(
  n = c(10L, 100L, 1000L),
  m = c(50L, 500L, 5000L),
  {
    mark(
      loop = {
        set.seed(123)
        totCount = vector("integer", n)
        for(j in 1:n) {
          s1 <- makeDNA(m) 
          count <- 0L
          for(i in seq_len(m-2L)) {
            if(s1[i] == "A" & s1[i+1] == "T" & s1[i+2] == "G") {
              count <- count + 1L
            }
          }
          totCount[j] <- count
        }
        totCount
      },
      subset = {
        set.seed(123)
        replicate(n, {
          s1 <- makeDNA(m) 
          sum(s1[1:(m-2L)] == "A" & s1[2:(m-1L)] == "T" & s1[3:m] == "G")
        })
      },
      stringi = {
        set.seed(123)
        replicate(n, {
          s1 <- makeDNA(m) 
          stringi::stri_join(s1, collapse = "") %>% stringi::stri_count_fixed("ATG")
        })
      }
    )
  }
)
```

The benchmark results can be plotted

```
library(ggplot2)
autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

The `for` loop is almost always slowest while subsetting almost always is fastest. For OP's use case with `m == 500L`, subsetting is more than 20 times faster than the `for` loop.

For large `m`, string operations are on par with (or slightly ahead of) subsetting.